# How to automatically open an email and click on a link with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, email, yahoo, fitbit

I am trying to optimize a code for retrieving fitbit data from a bunch of individuals. I have already optimized a python code using selenium that logins in their fitbit account and request the generation of their long-life data. Once these data are requested fitbit send an email with an activation link, that needs to be clicked on in order for the data to become available todownload in the fitbit account.

I would like to authomize this step of activation and therefore I want to automatically open the email in yahoo sent by fitbit (gmail doesn't allow automatic logins anymore) in order to be able to click on or open this link. However, probably since I am still a beginner with selenium I do not know how to open this mail and retrieve the link.

I am simply able to login and open the mailbox with this code below:

```
EMAIL="myaccount@yahoo.com"
PASSWORD="mypassword"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathtochromedriver')

url = "https://login.yahoo.com"
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys(EMAIL)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='signin']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']"))).send_keys(PASSWORD)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='login-signin']"))).click() #click on next

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='D(ib) Fz(14px) Fw(b) Lh(24px) Pstart(38px)']"))).click() #click on next


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(EMAIL)# Enter email address

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/div[2]').click() # Click next button after entering email address
```

However I cannot "inspect" the xpath of the incoming mail. Is there a way to locate these elements to open the fitbit mail and retrieve or click on the activation link?

Thanks

Comment: FitBit has a web API.  That has to be 50x easier than this kind of nonsense.  Did all of these people really give you authorization to pull their data?  That's unbelievable to me.

Comment: they received a fitbit for the longitudinal study so of course they agreed, thanks for the heads up on the fitbit API. Of course the yahoo accounts had been created from us and are not their real accounts.

Comment: can you share the code that logs in to fitbit accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))).send_keys(EMAIL)
```

You can use By.ID to click the button (or link) by it's id.
You can learn more [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#).

[image]

If you want to inspect, just click around the edge of the white part.
Look for a div with this: class="D_F em_N gl_C ab_C W_6D6F H_6D6F".

Comment: Thanks, I knew about that and I actually used the same construction in my example. However, the problem is that, differently from normal web pages, I cannot inspect on the emails to check their ID or xpath. If I right-click, instead of seeing chrome commands like INSPECT, I see yahoo's commands associated to the email.

Comment: You can use `ctrl + shift + I` to open the inspection tools. It won't take you directly to the element you're looking at, but as you mouse over elements, they get highlighted in the page, so it's not too difficult to find what you're looking for